# Shell command to find highest number. But issue is double digit after decimal is not considered highest

Tags: linux, awk, sed, cut

Using shell script to find highest number out of the values mentioned in a variable.

For example

VAR="2011.2/2009.1/2011.10"

Shell script should identify 2011.10 is highest of of three
Output should be 2011.10

if VAR="2011.10/2011.1"
output should be 2011.10

if VAR="2010.1/2011.2"
output should be 2011.2

Issue here is that after decimal point double digit number are considered lower than single digit after decimal point.

Comment: You do realize that `2011.2 > 2011.10` and `2011.10 = 2011.1`, right?

Comment: this can not be called as float numbers comparison

Comment: No 2011.10 > 2011.2 and 2011.10 > 2011.1

Comment: @user8554534, according to your last comment - then, why `2011.10` should be treated as highest?

Comment: it should recognize as numbers after decimal as 10, 11, 12

Comment: mentioned correctly in question "2011.2/2009.1/2011.10" output is 2011.10
if VAR="2011.10/2011.1" output should be 2011.10

if VAR="2010.1/2011.2" output should be 2011.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you request is more like ***version*** numbers comparison.

**`tr`** + **`sort`** + **`head`** solution:

```
v="2011.2/2009.1/2011.10"
tr '/' '\n' <<<"$v" | sort -rV | head -1
2011.10
```

---

Test cases:

```
v="2011.1/2011.2"
tr '/' '\n' <<<"$v" | sort -rV | head -1
2011.2
```

---

```
v="2011.1/2011.2/2011.101"
tr '/' '\n' <<<"$v" | sort -rV | head -1
2011.101
```

Comment: @user8554534, you're welcome